# How do I use the Option::ok_or() method correctly?

Tags: error-handling, rust

I'm trying to understand how to use the question mark operator for error handling in Rust. I have this code:

```
fn main() -> Result<(), &'static str> {
    let foo: i32 = Some("1")
        .ok_or(Err("error 1"))?
        .parse()
        .or(Err("error 2"))?;
    Ok(())
}
```

This code can not be compiled for some reason:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `&str: std::convert::From<std::result::Result<_, &str>>` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:2:20
  |
2 |       let foo: i32 = Some("1")
  |  ____________________^
3 | |         .ok_or(Err("error 1"))?
  | |_______________________________^ the trait `std::convert::From<std::result::Result<_, &str>>` is not implemented for `&str`
  |
  = note: required by `std::convert::From::from`
```

[The Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html) has an example usage of the question mark operator:

```
use std::io;
use std::io::Read;
use std::fs::File;

fn read_username_from_file() -> Result<String, io::Error> {
    let mut s = String::new();

    File::open("hello.txt")?.read_to_string(&mut s)?;

    Ok(s)
}
```

In my opinion, it doesn't differ much from my example in sense of handling errors. I cannot see a reason for my code to be invalid. If the `From` trait should be implemented for all kinds of `Result` why does the code from the Rust book work fine?

Comment: This isn't to do with the `?` operator, exactly. You're not using `ok_or` correctly: it takes an `E`, not a `Result<T, E>`. `.ok_or("error 1")` makes it work

Comment: My bad! How could i miss that. Thank you!

Comment: @trentcl Would you like to post your comment as an answer? I think this is a valid question, and you gave a correct answer.

Comment: It is worth noting that when you get an error about `std::convert::From` is because you are using one type when other is expected, and there is no conversion between them. In this case, `std::convert::From<std::result::Result<_, &str>> is not implemented for &str` just means that you are writing a `Result<_, &str>` where a `&str` is required.

Comment: @rodrigo ... and because `?` implicitly uses `From` to convert between error types. I have added this to my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unlike `or`, `ok_or` takes an `E`, not a full `Result<T, E>` (because it wouldn't have anything to do if passed an `Ok`). Just pass the error string directly:

```
fn main() -> Result<(), &'static str> {
   let foo: i32 = Some("1")
       .ok_or("error 1")?
       .parse()
       .or(Err("error 2"))?;
    Ok(())
}
```

The reason the error message mentions the `From` trait is because `?` implicitly uses `From` to convert the expression's error type into the return value's error type. If it worked, `.ok_or(Err("error 1"))` would return a value of `Result<&'static str, Result<_, &'static str>>` (`_` could be almost anything, since `Err` doesn't specify). The `?` operator attempts to find an implementation of `From` that would convert `Result<_, &'static str>` (the expression's error type) into `&'static str` (the return value's error type). Since no such `From` implementation exists, the compiler emits an error.