# How do I take a selected field of the last element of the slice or return an error?

Tags: rust

I want to access the field `id` of the last element of my slice. The structure of elements that I store in my slice is defined as follows:

```
pub struct Element {
    pub id: [u8; 32],
    pub name: [u8; 16],
}
```

This is the function that I am using to access the element's id. I wanted to use the `last()` function, however, this function returns an `Option type` and  I have a problem to figure out how to correctly return the `id` within the `match` function

```
pub fn myfun(my_list: &[Element]) -> Result<[u8; 32], MyError> {
    let last_id = match my_list.last() {
        None => return Err(MyError::TheSliceIsEmpty),
        // ?? how should I map it here?
    };
    Ok(last_id)
}

pub enum MyError {
    TheSliceIsEmpty,
}
```

Comment: The duplicate [applied to your situation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ac5711bc2a4afc61db35761e8f0c4d2f).

Comment: See also [Why should I prefer `Option::ok_or_else` instead of `Option::ok_or`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45547293/155423); [How do I use the Option::ok_or() method correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54046081/155423).